# how to compile and run one single scala file without building whole project within intellij

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have several scala object in my project, sometimes I would like to run one single object whch has no dependency on any other object in the file (just want to see how it would behave before merging it into the whole project), but every time I click on "Run 'XXX'" (where xxx is the name of the object I would like to run, "hello world" for example), intellij tried to build the whole project, actually I just wanted to build and run the single scala object, like "helloword.scala".

I searched a lot and mostly the questions are about Java, if someone wants to run single Java class, then he can right click in the editor zone, then choose the "Run xxx.main()", but in my case ,I just can find the "Run xxx", 
someone said that cancel 'make' in run/debug configuration, but how and I didn't find 'make' button in the configuration.

so, anybody have an idea how to compile/build/run just one single scala object/file at one time in intellij?

BTW I am using the intellij idea 2019.1 and the project is based on maven.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `Build` action from `Before launch` section of the corresponding `Run/Debug Configuration` like so

1. Edit the [`Run/Debug Configuration`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) for the `Application` configuration type
2. Go to `Before launch` section
3. Remove `Build` action by clicking on the minus `-` button

You can test this out by creating two apps

```
// Run.scala file
object Run extends App {
  println("woohoo")
}
```

and

```
// RunBroken.scala file
obct RunBroken extends App {
  ptln("boom")
}
```

Create run configuration for `Run.scala` by following above instructions, and it should run despite there being a syntax error in `RunBroken.scala`.

Comment: cool, it works! I found another way: replace "build" with "build without error check", but I did not know I could actually remove the "build" button, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *Scratch File*.

Simply search for Scratch file in the actions search

[image]

And search for Scala in the languages dialog: (I'm using Java as an example, since I don't use Scala.)

[image]

This will create a new scratch which is accessible under `Scratches and Consoles -> Scratches` in the Project view.

As you can see here, there are Syntax Errors in a Project file

[image]

and yet, the Scratch file will compile and run:

[image]